# variable conflicts with declaration function.form1.userseqq

Tags: c#

when i try to run the followig script, it shows`'userseqq' conflicts with declaration function.form1.userseqq` and also it happens for `itemseqq` too.

Any idea?
Thank you

```
                int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
                int iid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_itemid.Text);
                for (int ywu = 0; ywu <= 92161; ywu++)
                {
                    int rwer = d[ywu];
                    if (rwer == uid)
                    {
                        int userseqq = ywu;
                    }
                }
                for (int yuyu = 0; yuyu <= 1258038; yuyu++)
                {
                    int er = d[yuyu];
                    if (er == iid)
                    {
                        int itemseqq = yuyu;
                    }
                }
                dotproduct(userseqq, itemseqq); //<--------the error line
                MessageBox.Show("The Score of item id " + itemseqq + " is " + result);
            }
```

Comment: According to the code you posted, those two values aren't in scope *at all* when you try to call the `dotproduct()` method.  Where else have you defined them?

Comment: I declare them at the beginning of the code as public integer, too @David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since itemseqq and userseqq are declared inside if {} statements, they are both out of scope when you try to use them.

Try to put both declaration at the top of your code like :

```
int iid;
int iid;
int itemseqq;
[...]
```

Edit : If you declare them before, get rid of the int keyword inside your if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, this won't work because `userseqq` and `itemseqq` are not visible to the line of code where you call the `dotproduct()` method.

Why are you declaring these variables inside your `if` statements?

Comment: I declare them at the beginning of the code as public integer, too @PaulG.

Comment: @user3446681 Well there's your issue and that's where the conflict comes from. Why re-declare them? Why not just modify their values?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

> I declare them at the beginning of the code as public integer, too

You shouldn't be re-declaring them in your method, then.  Where you do this:

```
if (rwer == uid)
{
    int userseqq = ywu;
}
```

You're declaring an *entirely new* instance of the `userseqq` variable, setting it, and then abandoning it.  I'm kind of surprised the compiler threw the error, but I guess the scoping of the variables in the compiled IL may be slightly different.  In any event, the error at least prevented the bug of not using the correct variables.

To use your class-level variables, don't re-declare:

```
if (rwer == uid)
{
    userseqq = ywu;
}
```

(The same is true of the `itemseqq` variable.)